# Can I run an iPhone app from Xcode without debugging it?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to have Xcode automatically launch an app on my iOS device from Xcode 4.6 without attaching its debugger to the app? I'm working on an automated build system, so manually launching the app is not an option.

I've found Run Without Building under the Product -> Perform Action menu, but that still attaches the debugger. I can edit the scheme to make Xcode wait until the app is launched manually before attaching the debugger, but that's basically the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Is the reason because you don't want to hit breakpoints? You can disable all breakpoints with that "Breakpoints" toggle in the toolbar. Just letting you know.

Comment: I'm trying to set up for running automated tests from a continuous build server and the debugger can interfere with the program's behavior.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to launch an app from Xcode without launching the debugger, I would uncheck the “Debug executable” option in the Xcode [scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ManagingSchemes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH56-SW13):

[image]

---

If you want to launch an app manually, you can:

- Select your device in the "scheme" dropdown;
- Build the app (don't run);
- Open the organizer and go to the "devices" tab;
- Drag your app from the "Products" folder in the main Xcode project navigator to the device in the organizer window and it will be installed; and
- You can then run the app manually from the device at that point.

This process can be useful when diagnosing startup performance and you want to run the app on the device completely separate from Xcode (and the debugger, if you have a debug build).

Comment: The "None" option is only available for the simulator, not for devices. Looks like there isn't a way.

Comment: The Apple link is down.

Comment: I’ve removed that old link

Comment: As someone who uses Visual Studio, I want to say, "Wow, this is so inconvenient!"

Answer (score 7):

Just Build and run and once it launches press stop and open the app manually. It will then be the app you built but not connected.

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to have Xcode launch the app without debugging it. I don't want to manually launch the app. This is for an automated build system. I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @greg Could you just edit the "scheme" so that the debugger is changed from "LLDB"/"GDB" to "None"? Also, you could build a "release version".

Comment: The "None" option isn't available for schemes that run on a device. "None" is only available when running in the simulator.

Answer (score 7):

xcode 6.3.1 
[image]

unselect the debug execute, then you could run without debugging.

Comment: How to access this view in XCode?

Comment: @SvenReuter - Click on the “scheme” bar (immediately to the left of where you choose the desired device/simulator)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete the **"Breakpoints"** file first from git and after that add it to your **".gitignore"** file

this file contains of your breakpoints:

Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist

it is in your project **.xcworkspace** file

your automated action no longer check it.

[image]